# MVC 4 partial view causes page to become unresponsive on submit

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Situation: In my C#/MVC 4 solution I am employing a view with a partial view within. The view is a form with a submit button. The partial view is with a div that is hidden, but can be displayed if the checkbox is selected.

Issue: If the partial view is hidden, the submit works normally. If the partial view is not hidden the submit causes the page to become unresponsive, if one waits the 3 plus minutes or so the submit eventually works as expected.

The code is below. Thank you in advance for your consideration. I am a novice developer, therefore all comments, suggestions and critiques are welcome.

Code:

Model

```
namespace MyModels
{
   public class MainModel
   {
       public SelectListItem Things { get; set;}

       public IEnumerable<OtherModel> MoreThings { get; set;}
   }
}
```

View
    //named MyView
    @model MyModels.MainModel
    @using MyModels
    @if (Model != null){

```
    using (Html.BeginForm("MyViewName", "MyControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "view-form" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.things)
    @Html.DropDownList("", (Selectist)ViewBag.things)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.field1)

    @Html.CheckBoxWithLabel("aNameAttribute", Model.valueAttribute.ToString(), "anIdAttribute", Model.valueAtttribue ==1, "aLabel", "a_Toggle_Class") 
    <div class="treeview" style="display: none;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Title</legend>
    //view causing issues replaces the div below
    <div id="replacedDiv"></div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
}
```

}

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $.ajax({
           url: "/MyController/MyPartialView",
           contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
           cache: "false",
           type: "GET",
           datatype: "html"
       })
       .success(function (result) {
           $('#replacedDiv").html(result);
       })
   });
</script>
```

Partial View

```
//named _MyPartialView
@model MyModels.MainModel
@using MyModels

@foreach (var moreThings in ViewBag.moreThings)
{
    <div id="replacedDiv">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" id=@moreThings.id value=@moreThings.name />@moreThings.name </label>
    </div>
}
```

Controller

```
namespace Main.Controllers
{
    public class MyController
    {
       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult Index(MainModel model)
       {
          return View(model);
       }

       public ActionResult MyView()
       {
           var model = new MainModel();

           return View(model);

       }

       public ActionResult MyPartialView(MainModel model)
       {
           <OtherModel> moreThings = BLotherModel.GetMoreThings();
           ViewBag.moreThings = moreThings;

           return PartialView("_MyPartialView", promotion);
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult MyView(FormCollection collection)
       {
          MainModel model = new MainModel();

          return SaveModel(model);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in your JavaScript.  While that may not be causing this specific problem, it's certainly not helping.

Comment: Remove certain elements from your code to figure out what's the root cause.

Comment: I just updated the javascript, it was a typo and not in actual code

Comment: I found this article.. http://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/03/11/resolving-controller-blocking-within-net-4-5-and-asp-net-mvc/  but am a little bit reluctant to make the change in IIS unless I'm sure there is nothing else that is causing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax you are using:

```
$('#replacedDiv").html(result);
```

But your partial view contains `<div id="replacedDiv">` that are generated in a loop

replace your partial view code with :

```
@foreach (var moreThings in ViewBag.moreThings)
{
    <label>@moreThings.name </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id=@moreThings.id value=@moreThings.name />
}
```

and it should be OK

Comment: The problem persist, however I well use this suggested change. It completely escaped my attention.

Comment: Try to open fiddler or some other network monitor( the one in the browser is OK as well) and check when the POST request is sent? If the request is sent immediately, the problem is on the server side.
Put a breakpoint on the first line of your post action. if there is a delay between request submission and a break point hit the problem may be with model binder/action filters or anything else that is getting executed prior to action itself.

Comment: ok so oddly enough the behavior doesn't occur in firefox so I'm going to go ahead and mark the original suggestion as the answer